# Is there a way to get a printout of specific selected lines of code in visual studio 2022 in windows 11?

Tags: printing, selection, visual-studio-2022, selected, windows-11

I have currently in visual studio version 17.6.4 and windows Version-10.0.22621 Build 22621. I am trying to get a printOut of selected lines of code. But there is no print preview and if I try to print it gives me option for printing all pages or custom range of pages. Previously in visual studio there used be an option for printing selected lines. If someone could help me that would be really good. [screenshot visual studio 2022 , windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX1jW.png)

Same file, when I open in visual studio 2005 and mark selected lines for printing gives me option to print selected lines. [screenshot visual studio 2005, windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7xro.png)